# How do I unlock more backgrounds?

Tags: neko-atsume

I can't tell what unlocks backgrounds that you can buy with gold fish. I have a lot of mementos and have taken picture of many of the cats. I haven't made a ton of goodie purchases though. What can I do to unlock more backgrounds?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an incomplete list of wallpapers and their unlock requirements on the [Neko Atsune Wiki](http://nekoatsume.wikia.com/wiki/Wallpapers).

[image: Background unlock requirements]

Answer (score 1):

I got the last one I was missing by buying all the pots and buckets.[image]